# Installation via composer: multiple git remotes and pathspec error during feature branch checkout

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I am installing our PHP application with composer and linked git repositories. After installation, the cloned repositories have two git remotes configured, 'composer' and 'origin'.

composer.json

```
"require": {
    [...]    
  "mycompany/myrepository":       "dev-master",
}, 
[...]
  "repositories": [
{
  "type": "vcs",
  "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/myrepository.git"
},
```

Right after composer completed the installation:

```
$> git remote show
composer
origin
```

When I want to switch to any available feature branch on the repository, it fails with a git error.

```
$> git fetch && git checkout branchname 
error: pathspec 'branchname' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

When I delete the git remote 'composer', it works fine but that isn't very scalable/efficient.

```
$> git remote rm composer
```

What might be wrong in my composer.json or the way I want to achieve this?

Edit:
The composer.json has been created based on https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md at the time - if I start fresh and only require a single module, no dependencies etc, and then do a `compser create-project`, the outcome is identical: both remotes "composer" and "origin" are available.

Update:
I tried doing the same with a single git public repo monolog/monolog based on composer documentation and it resulted in the same two remotes present.

Testcase from scratch:

```
{
  "require": {
    "monolog/monolog":       "dev-master"
  },

  "require-dev": {
  },

  "repositories": [

    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog"
    }
  ]
}

$ composer create-project
$ cd vendor/monolog/monolog
$ git remote show
composer
origin
```

Comment: You don't have a branch name 'branchname' so you can't do git checkout branchname. You only have origin and composer.

Comment: @Eyorther you are wrong. `git remote show` does not show the branches it shows which remotes are there. These can of course contain branches. Here `origin` and `composer` are not branches but remote repositories. But you are right with that there is no branch called `branchname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `git branch -a` to see which branches you have.

It should look something like

```
* master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/branchname
remotes/composer/master
```

If there is no **local** branch `branchname` you can

```
git fetch origin
git checkout --track origin/branchname
```

to track the `branchname` from `origin`.

Comment: From a git only perspective, I know how to correct my setup with two remotes as displayed within my queston. Your approach does indeed work too, I just tried it. 

What I am looking for, is a setup/configuration within composer itself which fully avoids having to do any manual git cleanup before pulling in the existing branch. My aim is to "not have the git remote "composer" there at all after 'composer install'" - just the origin which all subsequent git calls like `git fetch && git checkout branchname` default to.

Comment: I do not understand where that composer remote came from I never have a `composer` remote in any of my Composer projects. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I do not know this as well - but your git branch -a has a composer remote listed too or is that a mock-up?

Comment: That was a mock-up. How did you install your project? Can you add that to the question? Did you use `composer create-project`?

Comment: Updated the question - yes, it's the same result if I re-create from a scratch composer.json.

Comment: by starting from scratch you mean that you start in a new and completely empty folder that is no git repository right? Can you add the commands you used for testing/creating so I can see if I get the same result?

Comment: Yes, new and completely empty folder, not a git repo. I updated the question with the composer.json - thanks for your support!

Comment: That's impossible. If I create a test folder `/mono-test/` with your `composer.json` I definitely get a `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` within the `/mono-test/vendor/monolog/monolog/`. Do you have a subfolder in there that is named `.git`?

Comment: FYI, my composer version 1.2.2.

Yes, I have a .git within vendor/monolog/monolog with both remotes pointing to the GitHub repo.

Comment: OK, I got what happened  here. Use `--prefer-dist` as option when you create a project (or set it as default for Composer) and you do not have these `.git` folders in `/vendor`. Just to say: If you installed a project with Composer then you **never** need to touch whats inside the `/vendor` folder. If you do, then you do it wrong! Btw. update Composer `composer self-update` your version is outdated.

Comment: Thanks. First of all, I self-update composer when it tells me to, is there a better approach?

I have our internal library within /vendor/companyName where I develop too - there I need a .git - what is your approach?

--prefer-dist does what you say and it does not affect non /vendor installation paths (we use composer/installers to clone into module/Foo)

So full circle, I am back to square 1: double remotes in our repos where I develop and need to checkout branches.

Comment: Ahh, you are developing a package. This changes everything you didn't mention that before. In your `composer.json` you require `dev-master` so you get the master branch in your vendor. If you require `dev-branchname` you get the branch `branchname` in your vendor. Anyway you should be able to push/pull then as usual. According `composer self-update` I do it randomly or if I run into issues. First thing is updating composer to make sure that is no issue.

Comment: Thanks - will update the question. The big picture is that I want to quickly install a project created by a co-worker with composer which is set to dev-master initially. Then I switch manually to newly created branches for development work which failes due to multiple remotes present.

Comment: It sounds a bit strange to me to require the master branch and switch in the vendor to another branch. I suggest to change the requirement to `dev-branchname` and run a `composer update` to do a clean switch.

Comment: This has in 99% of all cases nothing to do with the vendor - since most of the work is done in modules which are then installed/located in module/<ModuleName>. 

When you work on modules/components/whatever, do you always switch to new feature branches with composer? I prefer the shell directly to switch to a feature branch.

The focus is development, not testing/CI/deployment.

Comment: Composer adds a `composer` remote so that you can change the origin URL (eg. if you need to push to your fork) and it won't interfere
with you. Composer only fetches data from the composer remote. This is why you need that composer remote. You have a local `master` branch because you required `dev-master` but you don't have a local branch `branchname`. So if you like to pull/push changes to origin then you will need to checkout the remote branch with `git checkout --track origin/branchname` as in my answer above. After that a local `branchname` exists and `checkout branchname` should work too

Comment: Thanks, I accept that my development setup might need improvement and that I can't configure composer to achieve this without effort :)

I therefore accepted your answer as this looks like the most correct way since removing the remote 'composer' is wrong from a composer point of view.

Comment: It sounds like you are not happy with that. If you like to change things in a branch `branchname` you need this branch as a local branch to work with. `git checkout --track origin/branchname` does exactly this. It creates a local `branchname` from origin and tracks it so that if you push your changes it knows to push it to origin. I see nothing wrong with that approach.

Comment: No - your approach is totally fine, and I am happy with that. I'm not happy with my own dev workflow so far :) 

The thing is, when I randomly clone one of our repos from our bitbucket repository let's say from the master branch, I can immediatley switch to any feature branch I created on bitbucket with git fetch && git checkout branchname - there is only one origin so git isn't confused as when composer is involved.